# Asynchronous execution of commands in Shell

Tags: shell, asynchronous

I have a csv file. Currently what my script is doing is:

1. Sorting two files parallely.
2. After step 1 is completed, I am cutting a column in both the files.
3. After step 2, I am diff-ing the files which I got from step 2.

What I want to do is, the moment step 1 is completed I want to go to the next row of csv and execute the sort command for that row (which mentions 2 files to be sorted according to step 1). That means while row 1 is on step 2, row 2 should be on step 1. How am I supposed to do this? Do I need some sort of data pipelining?

Sorry for the confusion. Pseudo code of what I am currently doing right now:

```
  sort col1_row1 > sorted_col1_row1 &
  sort col2_row1 > sorted_col2_row1 &

  wait for sorts

  cat sorted_col1_row1 | cut -f1-3 > cut_sorted_col1_row1 &
  cat sorted_col2_row1 | cut -f1-3 > cut_sorted_col2_row1 &

  wait for cat

  diff cut_sorted_col1_row1 cut_sorted_col2_row1 > diff_row1
```

When sorts gets over for row1 files, I want program to jump on row2 for execution with cat and diff running on row1 files.

Comment: What does it mean to "execute the sort command for [one] row"?

Comment: The csv file contains in each row path for 2 files.During step 1 I am sorting two files parallely(as mentioned in row 1). The moment I go to step 2, I want my program to read the next row of csv file and  sort the 2 files(mentioned in row number 2) and simultaneously work on step 2 for row 1.

Comment: Well, you could run step 2 and 3 in the background using a `( cmd1; cmd2; ) &` subshell block. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Your description is quite hard to understand. is this what you want?

```
( sort file1 | cut ... > step2.out ) &
sort file2 > step3.out &
wait
diff step2.out step3.out
```

Answer (score 0):

On the face of it, you should be using something like:

```
for suffix in row1 row2
do
    for prefix in col1 col2
    do
        base=${prefix}_${suffix}
        (sort $base | tee sorted_$base | cut -f1-3 > cut_sorted_$base) &
    done
    wait
    diff cut_sorted_col[12]_$suffix > diff_${suffix}
done
```

I'm assuming you need the `sorted_col1_row1` files that are the output of `sort`.  If you don't need them, remove the `tee` portion of the sub-command.

There's no reason to split the parallelism up with the sorts both completed before either `cut` starts.  The `sort` command is interesting anyway; it has to read all its input before it can generate any of its output, at least in its basic sort operating mode.  When it's used for merging, it can produce output before it reads all the input.